# ios UIView no init calls

Tags: ios

My current `storyboard` layout

```
UIViewController
  |
  +- UIView (MyView)
```

in `MyView` I have the following functions built out

- init
- initWithFrame
- initWithCoder
- awakeFromNib
- awakeAfterUsingCoder

Out of those five, only **two** actually run

- awakeFromNib
- awakeAfterUsingCoder

I've scoured for a while and I can't figure out why the `init` functions aren't working.

Comment: Hmmm... I would think `initWithCoder` would be the method that's called when unarchiving a UIView from a xib or storyboard file.  But maybe storyboards are doing something different?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I thought the same. Which is why I was surprised that it didn't work, but that `awakeAfterUsingCoder` did. Because that kind of implies that `initWithCoder` already ran..

Comment: @MichaelDautermann it was something simple. This is two days in a row now. I had `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder:(CGRect)frame`. Why is that it takes me so long to see these n00b mistakes? I don't know. In my defense, Xcode didn't give me any build errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per my comment up top:

@MichaelDautermann it was something simple. This is two days in a row now. I had - `(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder:(CGRect)frame`. Why is that it takes me so long to see these n00b mistakes? I don't know. In my defense, Xcode didn't give me any build errors.

*Incorrect* code I had:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder:(CGRect)frame {
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        //
    }
    return self;
}
```

**Correct** code:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        //
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't give build errors, because it's just another method you define... but nobody calls it. :)

Answer (score 0):

About `initWithFrame:` under the UIView class documentation

> If you use Interface Builder to design your interface, this method is
>   not called when your view objects are subsequently loaded from the nib
>   file.

From the [Resource Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html) under the Nib section

> In iOS, any object that conforms to the NSCoding protocol is initialized using the initWithCoder: method
>
> Custom views in iOS do not use the initWithFrame: method for initialization.

Does your custom view's interface declare itself as conforming to the `NSCoding` protocol?  That could be a reason why the `initWithCoder:` method isn't called

```
@interface MyView : UIView <NSCoding> {

}
```